# How to Bond Leg that I Broke of my Mini-Tripod?

Tags: tripod, repair

I have mini-tripod and today while opening, broke one of it's 3 legs forgetting about it's maximum 45-degree deployment corner:

[image]

[image]

I wanted to know if it's possible to bond broken part back and just in case I have JBWeld, general adhesive and I Super Glue (but not sure it's original).

Comment: Looks tough. I'd use JB Weld, but I wouldn't want to bet on it holding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two ways to fix this.

**Option 1.**

A) It looks like part of the female threads (black plastic) are still on the metal male threads.  First thing you'll need to do is GENTLY remove this broken piece.  You may be able to twist it off with your fingers, depending on how tight it is.  Otherwise, take a pair of pliers and twist it off.

B) Rotate the ball in the socket so that it is about centered in the head (so that any glue is less likely to get into the joint).  Take the black plastic piece and position it back against the tripod head and rotate it until you find the position it was in when it broke.  Make a small mark in the same place on both the black piece as well as the head with a sharpie, whiteout, pen, or pencil.  This will show you the proper orientation.  Put a moderate amount of Super Glue on the ball and realign the broken plastic piece.  Press the two pieces together for at least 60 second being careful not to move either piece.  Once it has cured (at least 2 hours), run a small bead of Super Glue around the break to reinforce it.  Wait 24 hours and then reassemble.  It won't be as strong as it was, but it should work for a while.

**Option 2. (if Option 1 fails)**

A) Do step A) from above, place the broken piece back on the male thread, add a generous amount of "5 Minute" epoxy (I've personally not had luck with JB weld...) to the male threads and broken plastic piece and press it back together.  Hold it for a couple minutes and it should be as good as new.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. So Option 1 is actually not optional but pre-requisite for Option 2?

Comment: I would do option 1 first.  If that doesn't work, or breaks, try option 2.

Answer (score 7):

I would throw it away and buy a replacement. Even if I could fix it, I don't think I'd trust it to hold my camera. If it breaks again with the camera on it, the camera may only fall a few inches or a foot; after all, it's a mini-tripod. But, what if it breaks and the camera falls those few inches, then falls several feet off of the object you had the tripod set on, breaking the camera? Unless it's a "tough"/shockproof camera, I don't think I'd chance it -- it's just not worth it to me to risk damaging the camera on something that's clearly going to be something of a hack repair job.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly how to fix this. I have used in the past a type of glue called "Mitre Mate" it is made by no-nonsense I think but I'm sure other similar products are available.

It sticks anything to anything and comes with a glue and an activator spray. I've used it in the past for all sorts and the latest was gluing copper pipes to each other.

That will definitely fix your tripod!